# Weight paint controlled texture?

Tags: shaders, weight-painting, procedural

Is there anyway to control the gradient with a weight paint? If so, how could I pull this off and how can I change the falloff for the weight paint for the eyes?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Vertex Groups (Weights) directly in the Shader editor. You can use color attributes (made in Vertex Paint mode), and transfer the weights to color attributes.

1. Go to Vertex Paint mode
2. Select the vertex group what you want to transfer
3. Use Paint>> Vertex Color from Weight
4. Add an Input>>Attribute node to the Shader editor and type in the Color Attribute's name to the "name" field. (Color attributes are located below the Vertex Groups on the right side in the mesh properties panel)

Of course you have to refresh it every time you modify the weights. You can use ColorRamp in the Shader editor or you can smooth the weights in Weight Paint mode to control the fall of. If you don't need the vertex groups for any other purpose you can use Vertex painting immediately.

[image]